# BeautifulSoup print multiple tag / attr

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

First off all, this is my first try on Python, so far it looks pretty easy to use, though I still ran into a problem..

I am trying to change an XML-file to an rss-XML
The original xml source looks like this:

```
<news title="Random Title" date="Date and Time" subtitle="The article txt"></news>
```

It shoold eventually look like this:

```
<item>
<pubDate>Date and Time</pubDate>
<title>Random Title</title>
<content:encoded>The article txt</content:encoded>
</item>
```

I am trying to do this using python and BeautifulSoup, using the following script

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

doc = [
'<news post_title="Random Title" post_date="Date and Time" post_content="The article txt">''</news></p>'
    ]
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(doc))

print soup.prettify()

posttitle = soup.news['post_title']
postdate = soup.news['post_date']
postcontent = soup.news['post_content']

print "<item>"
print "<pubDate>"
print postdate
print "</pubDate>"
print "<title>"
print posttitle
print "</title>"
print "<content:encoded>"
print postcontent
print "</content:encoded>"
print "</item>"
```

The problem here is, it only retrieves the most ontop string XML, and not the others.
Can anybody give me some directions in fixxing this?

Cheers :)

Comment: Can you give us some sample output?  Your description of the problem isn't very clear, since there is only one string of XML.

Comment: What means "most ontop string"?

Comment: The code looks perfectly fine for what you are asking. Do you have multiple <news> items to be parsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stealing the code and correcting it:

```
for news in soup.findAll('news'):
    posttitle = news['post_title']
    postdate = news['post_date']
    postcontent = news['post_content']
    print "<item>"
    print "<pubDate>"
    print postdate
    print "</pubDate>"
    print "<title>"
    print posttitle
    print "</title>"
    print "<content:encoded>"
    print postcontent
    print "</content:encoded>"
    print "</item>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example doc variable only holds one `<news>` element.

but in general you would need to loop through the news elements

something like

```
for news in soup.findAll('news'):
    posttitle = news['post_title']
    postdate = news['post_date']
    postcontent = news['post_content']
    print "<item>"
    print "<pubDate>"
    print postdate
    print "</pubDate>"
    print "<title>"
    print posttitle
    print "</title>"
    print "<content:encoded>"
    print postcontent
    print "</content:encoded>"
    print "</item>"
```

Comment: @Sentinel, ah yes.. i just copy/pasted.. change it to `news` since we are iterating for each element, and store the current item in `news`. Updated example.